# Using WebSocket.js as a JS module in place of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have a Websocket.JS that is defined as the following :

```
   class Websocket extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const url = Config.ws + Config.baseEndPoint + Config.pen;
        const protocol = this.props.protocol;
        const doesLogging = (this.props.doesLogging === "true");
        this.state = {"url": url,
                      "protocol": protocol,
                      "socket": new WebSocket(url, protocol),
                      "doesLogging": doesLogging};
      };

      onOpen() {

      }

      onMessage(msg) {

      }

      onClose() {

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div id="websocket"></div>
        );
      }

    }

    export default Websocket;
```

And use it in the app.js like this:

```
    import Websocket from './services/websocket';
    <Websocket handleMessage={(msg) => this.messageReceived(msg.data)} />
```

However, I want to use it just as a module without it being represented like an HTML element. Is there any possible I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that interaction via websockets must be presented in your code by using any kind of the UI library. Therefore:

```
   class YourWebsocket{

      constructor(protocol, url, enableLogging) {
        this.url = url;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.loggingEnabled = enableLogging;
        this.socket = new WebSocket(url, protocol);
        this.socket.onopen = (ev) => this.onOpen();
        // Assign more handlers here
      }

      onOpen() {

      }

      onMessage(msg) {

      }

      onClose() {

      }

      send(data, callback)
      {
        var listener = (e) =>
        {
            var reply = e.data;

            if(replyIsForOurRequest) //Here you should come up with the logic to decide if this is reply for your request
            {
                this.socket.removeEventListener("message", listener);
                callback(reply);                
            }
        };

        this.socket.addEventListener("message", listener);
        this.socket.send(data);
      }
    }

    export default YourWebsocket;
```

And in your app.js somewhere in `componentDidMount` method:

```
import YourWebsocket from './services/YourWebsocket';

class App extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.webSocket = new YourWebsocket();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I instantiate this in my app.js and couple it to the handler functions ? For example..callbacks in case of onMessage etc ?

Comment: Instantiation was already present in my example using `componentDidMount` method. For sending function - check my update.

Comment: Would there be any harm if I define the handlers after instantiation in componentDidMount() method ? For example this.websocket.onmessage = (msg) => {
      this.messageReceived(msg.data)
    };

Comment: Absolutely no problem here. You can move all logic for attaching handlers to separate `YourWebsocket.initialize()` method. And call it in `componentDidMount`.